# jQuery cannot parse HTML strings with prefixed white space?

Tags: jquery, space, prefix

Whether it be a tab space, one regular space or many, jQuery cries `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <div></div>`

Here's the code in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dc8fK/

Here's the code:

```
console.log( $("<div></div>") );    // works
console.log( $(" <div></div>") );   // not
```

Aside from searching and removing any prefixed white space, is there a better, more official way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call [`$.parseHTML()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/), which can parse arbitrary HTML strings.

Answer (score 1):

Notably, `$(“<html>”)` syntax now requires the first character to be ‘<’ to indicate an HTML template. 
So in places where you have whitespace, you can fix with a call to “trim”.

Although, As Slaks mentioned n according to me explicit call to $.parseHTML would fix it best.

Comment: `trim()` actually fixes the specific issue that I was having. I'd left those details out to keep the description simple.